# Should I use "in", "at," or "during"?

Tags: prepositions, time

As a general statement, which one is more correct?

> The pool looked gorgeous **in** the night.
>
> The pool looked gorgeous **at** night.
>
> The pool looked gorgeous **during** the night.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All three *could* be grammatically correct in colloquial English depending on the context. Here are some examples, though not exclusive:

1. The pool looked gorgeous in the night, but in the morning we saw trash at the bottom.
2. The pool looked gorgeous at night. [This is fine as is, and is the most likely usage.]
3. The pool looked gorgeous during the night, while lit by the floodlights.

Example 1 implies it might not always look good, and 3 implies a duration. English is flexible, and in this case, there is *no intrinsically wrong* answer.

Comment: Good answer. I'd emphasize that *at night* is used most "generally" to specify that something is true at nighttime as compared with other times. *When does it look best?* The standard answer would be: *At night.*

Answer (score 2):

Looked gorgeous in the night.... poetic/literary/slightly "heightened" diction.

At night.... normal register

During the night...   typically, things *happen* during the night; things do not seem beautiful *during* the night.  The word "throughout" would probably be a better choice than "during" if you want to link it to looking beautiful.