# Choice between ''in my freshman year' and 'during my freshman year'

Tags: prepositions, time

I am writing my essay and could someone possibly have a look at this sentence for me, please?

> My strong passion for education stems from my experience with Jack Liu, a teenage English learner who I tutored **during my freshman year**.

Which one is correct, 'during my freshman year' or 'in my freshman year'?
BTW, I am currently a senior college student.

Comment: As an aside, the more formally "correct" variation is **whom**, but **who** is okay too.

Comment: There is a difference. Read a related question -- **[during or in](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38904/difference-between-in-and-during)**. Or just google for "during or in" or "prepositions of time". 30 seconds' worth of googling [brought me this](http://www.englishgrammar.org/prepositions-time/): "When we are talking about the whole of the period we use **during**, not **in**."

Comment: Thank you CopperKettie. I think 'during' would be fitter here since I was referring to a long time period.

Comment: Do refer http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53851/should-i-use-in-at-or-during  too. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use

> whom I tutored **during my freshman** year

since it was a **duration** of time

> all **during** my freshman year

You would use **in** for a specific event which happened

> I began tutoring **in my freshman year**

Either **during** or **in** would be understandable, but if you are applying to graduate school, you may want to make the distinction.

[NB: your writing style sounds very AmE ]

Comment: "Both will have basically the same." ? I think you missed a word.

Comment: Thank you so much, Peter. And it's amazing that you even point out that my writing style sounds AmE. Is this style appropriate and formal for my application essay for graduate programs in the States? ( I've heard that British English writing style is more formal. )

Comment: Yes, it is, very much so, you will want to emphasis **what makes you different** than the other candidates, don't just say **your passion** give **examples**. They will want to know what you **acheived** both **inside** and **outside** the classroom. Good luck!

Comment: @Peter Just a heads-up: it's achieved not acheived.